# Why to serialise the use of an Android Service?

Tags: android, multithreading, serialization, service

I have some code sample from Google team, where it is written if the method called twice the use of the Service needs to be serialised, which I don't really understand what is the point. The method creates an Android Service and starts it to remove some data from the Database with an additional thread. I would like to hear some experts opinion to understand this comment.

```
 * We don't expect this to be called more than once.  If it were, we would have to
 * worry about serialising the use of the service.
 */
private void removeData(Context context, ContentResolver resolver) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, RemoveService.class));

    RemoveThread thread = new RemoveThread(context, resolver);
    thread.start();
}
```

EDIT: I didn't find the exact source code which I was looking at, but I have another version, where there is no Service start in the method, but it still has the same comment.

Please have look at the method `removeScheduledAlarms()`
[CalendarReceiver.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/4.4_r1/com/android/providers/calendar/CalendarReceiver.java#CalendarReceiver.removeScheduledAlarms%28android.content.ContentResolver%29)

Comment: "I have some code sample from Google team" -- you might consider linking to this code sample. It is unrealistic for you to expect people to explain a semi-random partial Java comment.

Comment: @CommonsWare, well, I will try to link it now, in my last question it worked without the link :)